# How to change the value of the Jenkin's Property/ParameterDefinition object

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins

Currently my setup contains a 2 projects/jobs, lets call them job1 and job2. My plugin would run stuff in a job1, and then it schedules a new builds in job2 with some parameters. I'm using the parameterized-trigger plugin in order to pass the params to new builds. Currently I can fetch the job2, and I can find the properties that contain the default param settings, that are needed in job2. But I cannot figure out how to modify the setting values from the job1. Thing is that each build in job2 needs their own param values, so those cannot be hardcoded, job1 generates those values.

```
void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, TaskListener listener) throws AbortException {
  // do stuff.

  Job job = getJobWithName("job2");

  if (job != null) {
    ParameterDefinition property = getProperty(job);

    if (property != null) {
      // TODO: how to modify the property?
    } else {
      // throw error 
    }
  }

  // starting a new build in a job2.
  if (job instanceof AbstractProject) {
    // TODO: change the Cause at some point
    ((AbstractProject) job).scheduleBuild(0, new Cause.UserIdCause());
  } else if (job instanceof WorkflowJob) {
    ((WorkflowJob) job).scheduleBuild(0, new Cause.UserIdCause());
  }
}


// fetches the correct job, in this case job2
private Job getJobWithName(String jobName) {
  Jenkins jenkinsInstance = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull();

  if (jenkinsInstance != null) {
    List<Job> jobs = jenkinsInstance.getAllItems(Job.class);

    for (Job job : jobs) {
      if (job.getDisplayName().equals(jobName)) {
        return job;
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

// fetches the correct property
private ParameterDefinition getProperty(Job job) {
  ParametersDefinitionProperty property = (ParametersDefinitionProperty) job.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty.class);

  for (ParameterDefinition pd : property.getParameterDefinitions()) {
    ParameterValue param = pd.getDefaultParameterValue();
    if (param != null) {
      if (name.equals("my_parameter_name") && pd.getType().equals("StringParameterDefinition")) {
        return pd;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
job.addProperty(new ParametersDefinitionProperty(
new StringParameterDefinition("StringProp", "DefaultValue1"), 
new BooleanParameterDefinition("BoolProp", false, "Desc")));
```